# How to avoid code duplication in router handling code

Tags: go, refactoring

I have a big router:

```
router.HandleFunc("/tags", controllers.GetTags)
router.HandleFunc("/tags/items/{tagId}", controllers.GetTaggedItemsByTagId).Methods("GET")
// ...
```

Each of such functions looks like:

```
func GetTags(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    tags, err := (&postgres.TagsService{}).GetTags()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(500)
    } else {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        resp, _ := json.Marshal(tags)
        w.Write(resp)
    }
}

func GetTaggedItemsByTagId(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    tagId, err :=  strconv.Atoi(vars["tagId"])
    items, err := (&postgres.TagsService{}).GetTaggedItemsByTagId(tagId)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(500)
    } else {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        resp, _ := json.Marshal(items)
        w.Write(resp)
    }
}
```

In each of these functions I get the data from the database, serialize result to `json` and return it to client.

I need something to avoid code duplication. Something like:

```
func Handler(err error, data object) {
   if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(500)
    } else {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        resp, _ := json.Marshal(object)
        w.Write(resp)
    }
}
```

I can not do this way as Go is typed language. What is the best way in Go to avoid code duplication in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a type for the function signature for each of the http handlers

```
type HandlerFunc func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) (interface{}, error)
```

Then wrap the functions like this

```
func WrapHandler(h HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

        d, err := h(w, req)

        // handle errors and sending out the data 
}
```

Then set the handlers using

```
router.Get('/myroute', WrapHandler(GetTaggedItemsByTagId))
```